# Как удалить регулярным выражением все теги, кроме <tr>?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть html файл,  который описывает некую таблицу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Необходимо преобразовать файл в следующий вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
код который удаляет все теги `.replaceAll("<[^>]+>|&([\\s\\S]+?);", "")`

Как я понимаю нужно удалить все теги, кроме tr,
а tr заменить на вертикальную черту?

Comment: А то что внутри тега, то же удалять?

Comment: Да.
У меня получился такой вариант - str.replaceAll("\\n", "")
        .replaceAll("</tr> ","\n")
        .replaceAll("<td>", "|")
        .replaceAll("</td>", "|")
        .replaceAll("<tr>", "|")
        .replaceAll("<[^>]+>|&([\\s\\S]+?);", "")
        .trim();

Comment: тогда я исправил свой вариант

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String code = "<tr>tr</tr> <br> br</br> <arr>arr</arr";
        String newStr = code.replaceAll("<tr>", "|").replaceAll("</tr>", "|")
                .replaceAll("<[ =-~]+>.+</[ =-~]+>", "");
        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
```

Вывод:
`|tr|  <arr>arr</arr`